# ionic4 App - landing page shows for few milliseconds before loading controller page during start up

Tags: ionic4

I would like to **show loading page for few seconds before landing page**, yes i have achieved it using loading controller in ionic4, while doing so landing page make appearance for split of second before landing page, i have tried lot of options of calling loading function at different different place but nothing works. Below is app.component.ts file. Kindly help.

```
export class AppComponent {
       constructor(
        private platform: Platform,
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
        private loadingController: LoadingController
      ) { 
        this.presentLoadingWithOptions();   
        this.initializeApp(); 
      }


      initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.statusBar.styleLightContent;
          this.splashScreen.hide();      

        });
      }

       async presentLoadingWithOptions() {
        const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
          spinner: null,
          duration: 8000,
          message:' Relax Take a Deep Breath ' ,
          translucent: true,
          cssClass: 'custom-class custom-loading'
        });
        return await loading.present();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that every async function returns a Promise object.

You should wait for the loading controller to dismiss before invoking `initializeApp`.

I would rewrite into something like:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
  private platform: Platform,
  private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
  private statusBar: StatusBar,
  private loadingController: LoadingController
) { 
  this.presentLoadingWithOptions()
    .then(() => this.initializeApp());
}

initializeApp() {
  ...
}

async presentLoadingWithOptions() {
  const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    spinner: null,
    duration: 8000,
    message:' Relax Take a Deep Breath ' ,
    translucent: true,
    cssClass: 'custom-class custom-loading'
  });
  loading.present();
  return await loading.onDidDismiss(); // Will resolve after 8000ms
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer...it is not working, i tried it again

Comment: there is no error, all code is working fine only problem is landing page make appearance for split of second and then come loading page where as requirement is landing page only come when loading page dismiss

Comment: please check in youtube link too, at 0:13 landing page appear for split of second before loading page. https://youtu.be/jF5A-6_bMck